# Visual Studio 2022 not showing Git Merges as expected

Tags: visual-studio, git-merge, visual-studio-2022

When I merge a feature branch into main, Visual Studio seems to just stack all the commits from the feature branch *on top* of main, rather than alongside it.

Visual Studio 2022's Git Repository / "Manage Branches" window displays a graph that seems to reflect every merge (of a feature branch into main) as a rebase- stacking all the feature branch's commits on top of main. I don't believe this is a result of Git's tendency to fast-forward merge, as there are some changes made to main after the branch was created (which aren't reflected as changes to "main"). [This is the Commit Graph in question- the blue and red circles are commits that were separate branches before being merged into main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhXR.png)

This isn't a functional issue (the code itself works fine), but it reads poorly and the graph doesn't work well with my team's workflow.

tl;dr Why do the commits of a given branch in VS2022 just seem to get stacked on top of main after merging?